# changing header based on URL in Angular

Tags: angular

in my application I have two apps inside, first one is Basic which has routes like:
localhost:4200/form,
localhost:4200/reports, 
localhost:4200/views, 
but now I have now on the second which is Advanced, I want to set routes like:
localhost:4200/advanced/views
localhost:4200/advanced/forms
and the header should be different as well.

here is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'report', component: ReportComponent },
      { path: 'form', component: RequestFormComponent},
      {
        path: 'advanced',
        component: AdvancedLevelComponent,
      },
      { path: 'aform', component: PmCustomerFormComponent }

    // I have tried: 
    {
        path: 'advanced',
        component: AdvancedLevelComponent,
        childern:[
            {{ path: 'aform', component: PmCustomerFormComponent }}
        ]
      },
      // but it it asks for <router-outlet></router-outlet> in that component and hence it 
render view in same page, I want it be like go to new page with URL: /advanced/aForm
```

and my header file:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <img [src]="logo" class="logo" routerLink="/mainpage">
  <span class="title">
   Basic
  </span>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-toolbar *ngIf="router.url==='/advanced'">
  <img [src]="logo" class="logo" routerLink="/mainpage">
  <span class="title">
  Advanced
  </span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

but route.url only works for the main advanced page not for it sub pages

Comment: Why dont you just catch your route and if it match to for example "advanced..."
put some header else the other header?
that what I do in my applications.
there is no other way to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it:

in your header.ts

```
import {Location,LocationStrategy,PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

and

```
   @Component({
     providers: [
     Location,
     { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }
     ]
)}
```

and create function like:

```
isAdvancedRoute(): boolean {
        return this.location.path().indexOf('/advanced') > -1;
      }
```

finally at

.html

```
*ngIf="isAdvancedRoute()"
```